# SwiftUI: Editable TextFields in Lists

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-text

##### *** NOTE: This question concerns macOS, not iOS ***

## Context:

I have a list of items that serves as a "Master" view in a standard Master-Detail arrangement. You select an item from the list, and the detail view updates:

[image]

In SwiftUI, this is powered by a `List` like this:

```
struct RuleListView: View
{
    @State var rules: [Rule]
    @State var selectedRuleUUID: UUID? 
    
    var body: some View
    {
        List(rules, id: \.uuid, selection: $selectedRuleUUID) { rule in 
            RuleListRow(rule: rule, isSelected: (selectedRuleUUID == rule.uuid))
        }
    }
}
```

## The Problem:

The *name* of each item in the list is user-editable. In AppKit, when using `NSTableView` or `NSOutlineView` for the list, the first click on a row selects that row and the second click would then begin editing the `NSTextField` that contains the name.

In SwiftUI, things have apparently gotten dumber. Clicking on ANY text in the list *immediately* begins editing that text, which makes selecting a row VERY difficult—you have to click on the 2 pixels above or below the `TextField` in each row.

To combat this, I've stashed a clear `Button()` on top of every row that's not selected. This button intercepts the click before it reaches the `TextField()` and selects the row. When the row is selected, the `Button()` is no longer included and subsequent clicks then select the `TextField()`:

```
struct RuleListRow: View
{
   var rule: Rule
   var isSelected: Bool

   var body: some View
   {
       ZStack
       {
            Label {
                TextField("", text: $rule.name)
                    .labelsHidden()
            } icon: {
                Image(systemName: "lasso.sparkles")
            }
            
            if !isSelected
            {
                Button {
                    // No-op
                } label: {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.clear)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
            }
        }
   }
}
```

## Question:

The above works, but...this can't be correct, right? I've missed something basic that makes `List` behave properly when it contains `TextField` rows, right? There's some magic viewModifier I'm supposed to stick somewhere, I'm sure.

What is the correct, canonical way to solve this issue using Swift 5.5 and targeting macOS 11.0+?

---

##### Note:

My first approach was to simply disable the `TextField` when the row isn't selected, but that caused the text to appear "dimmed" and I couldn't find a way to override the text color when the `TextField` is disabled.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but in my experience, although much of SwiftUI absolutely is production-ready, `List` on macOS is an uphill battle and you may be better off wrapping `NSTableView` than fighting `List` (this likely won't be the only issue you encounter with it).

Comment: Works as expected (at least at my replication) - first click selects row, second one activates editing. Xcode 13.3 / macOS 12.3.1

Comment: @Asperi - If I click anywhere in the row that is NOT text, the first click selects the row. But clicking on the TextField itself in a non-selected row edits the field without selecting the row.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `List` instead of a `LavyVStack` ?

Comment: @yawnobleix - Yes. `List` supports selection. `LazyVStack` does not (without a bunch of manual work--precisely the thing SwiftUI is supposed to eliminate).

Comment: Then needed minimal complete reproducible example, probably some other your code introduces conflict or something.